# How do I connect to Azure synapse dedicated pool from a spark application in k8s?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-eks, azure-synapse

So the main question is how can I connect to an azure synapse dedicated pool without databricks and connect it via an external spark app that runs on eks.
What driver should I use?

Currently, I have a scala-spark code and I compile it to generate a flat jar and I added a jdbc jar connector but I don't know if this driver is the correct one for synapse or if I need another extra driver for synapse because I have some issues when I try to write to a synapse-dedicated table.

Drivers:

```
jdbc: "com.microsoft.sqlserver" % "mssql-jdbc" % "9.4.0.jre11",
scala: "2.12.10"
java 11
spark: 3.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a dedicated sql pool in Azure synapse . Also , created a table 'tableA' and inserted one row in it. I want to connect to the sql pool using Synapse notebook and get the content of the table using spark session. For this , I am using pyspark code for doing that.

[image]

1. Create a new notebook and attach spark pool with it .
2. Create a code cell to initialize parameters which holds connection details for your dedicated sql pool

[image]

3. Create a new cell and add the below piece of code to connect to ded sql pool and retrieve the content of the table

```
import pyodbc as odbc 
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession 

filecontent=""" select top 10 * from tableA""" 

odbcConnectionString = 'Driver={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}};Server={0};Database={1};UID={2};PWD={3}'.format(dedsqlpoolname,dedsqlpooldbname,dedsqlpoolusername,password) 

sqlCon = odbc.connect(odbcConnectionString) 

sqlCursor = sqlCon.cursor() 

df1 = pd.read_sql(filecontent, sqlCon) 

display(df1) 

df2 = pd.DataFrame(sqlCursor.execute(filecontent)) 

sqlCon.commit() 

sqlCon.close()
```

[image]